# Template nullary metafunction in boost

Tags: c++, templates, boost

In the documentation related to the MPL library offered by Boost ([here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction.html), for example) one can find the following construct:

> typedef f<>::type x;

The only ways I can think the above is valid are if **f** is a template with variadic parameters or if **f** has default template parameters. In this context however, I think the former does not apply, as the MPL library appeared before variadic template parameters.

I have two questions:

1. Does the documentation refer to the case when **f** has default template parameters (considering the state of the language when the documentation was written)?
2. Considering the current state of the language (at the time of the post, I believe C++ 17 ) are there any other possibilities for the quoted construct to be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the declaration `typedef f<>::type x;` is valid whenever f is a class template ( or a template alias as of >=c++11 ) accepting no arguments with corresponding specialization having a member type 'type'. Given that no primary template definition can have no arguments, this means that either f has default arguments or that ( as of >=c++11 ) it's a variadic template with an empty argument pack.

> Does the documentation refer to the case when f has default template parameters (considering the state of the language when the documentation was written)?

yes, but keep in mind that MPL emulated variadics via default, placeholder types.

> Considering the current state of the language (at the time of the post, I believe C++ 17 ) are there any other possibilities for the quoted construct to be valid?

as far as I know and given the expression exactly as shown, the only other possibility is the aforementioned variadic class/alias template with empty pack.

Comment: When you say: "with corresponding specialization having a member type 'type'", what kind of specialization are you referring to? I think you could specialize f for matching on an empty parameter pack. Is this what you had in mind? Thank you.

Comment: I referred to the result of the f<> instantiation ( yes, that's still called a specialization in standardese )...

Comment: Ok. I was thinking that the only way a specialization could not have a 'type' member was (1) (template with default parameters) the primary template does not have it or (2) (template with variadic parameters) the primary template does not have it or there is a specialization that matches the empty parameter pack which does not have it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean ... any class template may have or may not have a member type named 'type' and any class template can be *partially specialized* to have it or not ...

Comment: I was trying to say that if f had default parameters, no matter what specializations it had, f<> would instantiate the primary template, therefore only the primary template would have to have a 'type' member. Only if f had variadic parameters, then f<> could have instantiated a specialization different from the primary template.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't know you could do that. So when you use f<>, first it looks at the primary template to find the default value of the parameters, then it behaves as if you wrote f<Default>, looking both at the primary template and at the specializations, to see which one 'fits' best, am I right? Thank you again.

Comment: yep, the defaults are 'read' when the template name is introduced ( that is, when the primary template definition is parsed ). Then, partial specializations are matched as usual ...